# How to force the content of a DIV to the bottom?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm attempting to force the content of a DIV to be aligned at the bottom so that it aligns to the bottom of my google map. See here: http://dev.whydidibother.com/osteria/2_2_2015/#map

I've tried using relative positioning on the outer DIV and absolute position of the DIV that contains the content but cannot get it to align with the bottom of the map i.e. the Facebook address should align to the bottom edge of the map

Any ideas?

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: You want the `facebook` line to be aligned w/ the bottom of the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've set the `height` for your map, you already have it.

```
.contact-address-social-media-icons {
    height: 400px;
}
.contact-address-social-media-icons > div {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```